# How can you enhance a TabControl to dock and float TabItems or documents?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, tabcontrol, dock, avalondock

I have a `TabControl` that allows users to manage documents such as the following:

[image]

At some point, I want to add a feature that allows users to float `TabItem`s and dock them back into the `TabControl` much along the lines of what you can do in Visual Studio.  This feature will allow users to more easily compare documents and copy/paste between them, etc.

I have some general ideas on how to go about doing this.  The `TabControl` has its `ItemsSource` bound to a list of document view models.

To float the tab:

1. Add a `Thumb` control to the tab strip area of the `TabItem`.
2. When the user drags the `Thumb`, the associated document view model is removed from the `TabControl` list.
3. A separate document `Window` is brought up, bound with the document view model, to display/edit that document.

To dock the tab:

1. Add a `DragOver` event handler in the `TabControl` to recognise a document `Window` dragging over the tab strip area.
2. The associated document view model is added to the `TabControl` list.
3. The document `Window` is closed.

Are there any examples out there on how to do this, or do you have an approach to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: have a look at [AvalonDock](http://avalondock.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Excellent, I'll check AvalonDock out, thanks!

Comment: Have a look at [AvalonDock](http://avalondock.codeplex.com/). I believe AvalonDock does use separate windows. If using MVVM, I think you have to define a `DataTemplate` for each ViewModel (i.e. you can't define a View in a Window class).

Comment: Thanks jberger, this is likely the route I'll choose, I'll keep the question open for a little while longer.

Comment: no prob. the project had been stagnant for months and has recently picked up activity.. so it may be worth watching

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can't find or don't want to use a pre-existing control, I would highly recommend Bea Stollnitz's article about [dragging and dropping between databound controls](http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/?p=53). You will probably have to alter it a bit to work with a `DockPanel` to identify what `DockPanel.Dock` the databound object should use, however I've found the code easy to alter in the past.

You would then setup two databound controls, such as a `TabControl` and a `DockPanel`, and when dragging/dropping between the two you are actually dragging/dropping the databound items between the `ItemsSources`.

Comment: Good reference, thanks Rachel.  With that sample, have you tried working around the limitation of current Window only?  Ideally, I would want to have separate windows for the undocked documents.

Comment: @DaveClemmer No, I haven't tried it out with multiple windows, although I have used it to drag/drop items between different `UserControls`

Comment: @DaveClemmer: I believe AvalonDock does use separate windows. If using MVVM, I think you have to define a `DataTemplate` for each ViewModel (i.e. you can't define a View in a Window class).

Comment: @jberger, the AvalonDock approach is looking pretty likely for my needs, and I've got `DataTemplate`s set up.  You can post your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

I finally got around to implementing this feature, and I used [AvalonDock 2.0](http://avalondock.codeplex.com/), which is MVVM friendly.  All I needed to do was to replace the `TabControl` with a `DockingManager` and modify a few `Style`s.

The `DockingManager` setup (I only have documents, not tools, etc.):

```
<avalonDock:DockingManager x:Name="tabDesigner" DocumentsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <avalonDock:DockingManager.LayoutItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type avalonDockControls:LayoutItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource DocumentItem}"/>
    </avalonDock:DockingManager.LayoutItemContainerStyle>
    <avalonDock:DockingManager.DocumentPaneControlStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type avalonDockControls:LayoutDocumentPaneControl}" BasedOn="{StaticResource DocumentPane}"/>
    </avalonDock:DockingManager.DocumentPaneControlStyle>
    <avalonDockLayout:LayoutRoot>
        <avalonDockLayout:LayoutPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <avalonDockLayout:LayoutDocumentPane/>
        </avalonDockLayout:LayoutPanel>
    </avalonDockLayout:LayoutRoot>
</avalonDock:DockingManager>
```

I didn't need to use AvalonDock's template selectors, I was able to use the `DataTemplate`s that were already set up for the previous `TabControl`.

I modified the `LayoutItem`, `LayoutDocumentPaneControl`, and `LayoutDocumentTabItem` `Style`s to do the extra binding to the view models and other layout differences (it took a little while to figure out how to bind to the view models that are within AvalonDock's model):

```
<Style x:Key="DocumentItem" TargetType="{x:Type avalonDockControls:LayoutItem}">
    <Setter Property="Title" Value="{Binding Model.TabTitle}"/>
    <Setter Property="CloseCommand" Value="{Binding Model.CloseConfirmCommand}"/>
    <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding Model.IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="DocumentPane" TargetType="{x:Type avalonDockControls:LayoutDocumentPaneControl}">
    ...
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type avalonDockControls:LayoutDocumentPaneControl}">
                <Grid ClipToBounds="true" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Local">
                    ...
                    <Grid  Panel.ZIndex="1" Background="{DynamicResource TabControlHeaderBrush}" >
                        ...
                        <avalonDockControls:DocumentPaneTabPanel x:Name="HeaderPanel" Grid.Column="0" IsItemsHost="true" Margin="4,0,16,0" Grid.Row="0" KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="1"/>
                        <avalonDockControls:DropDownButton
                            ...
                            Style="{DynamicResource ToolBarHorizontalOverflowButtonStyle}"
                            Grid.Column="1">
                            ...
                        </avalonDockControls:DropDownButton>
                    </Grid>
                    <Border x:Name="ContentPanel" 
                            ...
                            CornerRadius="3">
                        <Border
                            ...
                            >
                            <Border
                                ...
                                >
                                <ContentPresenter x:Name="PART_SelectedContentHost" 
                                              ContentSource="SelectedContent" 
                                              SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                            </Border>
                        </Border>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    ...
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle">
        <Setter.Value>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                ...
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                            <Grid>
                                <ContentPresenter 
                                    x:Name="Content" 
                                    ContentSource="Header" 
                                    ... 
                                    SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <avalonDockControls:LayoutDocumentTabItem Model="{Binding}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>

    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <avalonDockControls:LayoutDocumentControl Model="{Binding}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type avalonDockControls:LayoutDocumentTabItem}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type avalonDockControls:LayoutDocumentTabItem}">
                <ControlTemplate.Resources>
                    ...
                </ControlTemplate.Resources>
                <Grid x:Name="grid" Margin="8,1,8,0">
                    ...
                    <Grid RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                        ...
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="3,0,2,0">
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="TabContent" Content="{Binding Model, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" TextBlock.Foreground="{DynamicResource UnselectedTabText}"
                                              ContentTemplate="{Binding DocumentHeaderTemplate, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type avalonDock:DockingManager}, Mode=FindAncestor}}"
                                              ContentTemplateSelector="{Binding DocumentHeaderTemplateSelector, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type avalonDock:DockingManager}, Mode=FindAncestor}}"
                                              Margin="5,2,5,2"/>
                            <Button
                                x:Name="TabItemButton"
                                Command="{Binding Path=Model.Content.CloseConfirmCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                Content="X"
                                ...
                            />
                            <StackPanel.ContextMenu>
                                <ContextMenu>
                                    <MenuItem Header="{Binding Model.Content.CloseTabLabel, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Command="{Binding Model.Content.CloseTab, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" ToolTip="{Binding Model.Content.CloseTabToolTipLabel, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"></MenuItem>
                                    <MenuItem Header="{Binding Model.Content.CloseOtherTabsLabel, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Command="{Binding Model.Content.CloseOtherTabs, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" ToolTip="{Binding Model.Content.CloseOtherTabsToolTipLabel, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"></MenuItem>
                                    <MenuItem Header="{Binding Model.Content.NextTabLabel, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Command="{Binding Model.Content.NextTab, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" ToolTip="{Binding Model.Content.NextTabToolTipLabel, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"></MenuItem>
                                </ContextMenu>
                            </StackPanel.ContextMenu>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    ...
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

This is an example of the end result:

[image]